# Number missing! Replace the question mark

Tags: cipher

A number is missing. Find "?".

((13 19  4□)⁽⁷ ⁴ ⁻¹⁾□) + ((14 6 4□ 3□ 5)⁽⁶ ² ² ⁻⁴  ⁾□) + (4□ 13 12 5 23 5)⁽⁴ ¹⁰ ⁻⁷ ⁷ ⁻¹  ⁾ = 
?□

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we

> interpret □ as meaning, naturally enough, "squared", and
>  interpret exponentiation as meaning "add correspondingly-placed numbers", and
>  then interpret via A1Z26,

we get

> TWO squared + THREE squared + TWELVE = ? squared

so, given that we're asked for a number, we should replace the question mark with

> 5.

Though I wonder whether actually something more like

> (9 13 3□ 10)⁽⁻³ ⁻⁴ ¹³ ⁻⁵⁾

would be more appropriate.